# How to disable text box until previous textbox has been populated?

Tags: vba, textbox, disabled-input

I have a userform which is made up of a single combobox followed by multiple text boxes.

How would I disable and grey out each textbox, preventing any user input unless the textbox above it has been populated?

I tried both of these techniques.

```vb
Me.CSockett.Enabled = Not IsNull(Me.CSocketl)

'If CSocketl.Value = "" Then
'    Me.CSockett.Enabled = False
'    Else
'    Me.CSockett.Enabled = True
'End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new `UserForm` with 2 `TextBox` all with default names. You can apply this concept to each textbox you need to.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If Not Me.TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    Me.TextBox2.Enabled = True
    Me.TextBox2.BackColor = &H80000005
Else
    Me.TextBox2.Enabled = False
    Me.TextBox2.BackColor = &H80000016
End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.TextBox2.Enabled = False
Me.TextBox2.BackColor = &H80000016

End Sub
```

The `Initialize` code disables the 2nd textbox and sets the background colour (see below) to visually show it's disabled when the form first opens.

The `Change` code evaluates on each change to the `TextBox.Text` property if the next textbox should be enabled or not.

**Note:** With a bit of searching you will find a million other ways to check for an empty textbox other than `...Text = ""`.

### UserForm when first opened (`Initialize` Code):

[image: Initialized userform with no input to textbox1]

### After typing a character into textbox1:

[image: Form after entering "A" into textbox1 showing textbox2 is now enabled]

The `.Enabled` property if set to `False` will not let the user click or tab to the `Control` (in this case, the `TextBox`). I add the `BackColor` change to have a visual aide showing the user it's 'greyed out' - otherwise it looks the same as an enabled `textbox` and can cause frustration to the user.

Naturally, the colour is set back to the default value once enabled.

Comment: Nice, thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it more flexible (that means you can use it for a lot of textboxes) I created three classes which handle the textbox event and also define an own event to enable resp. disable the textboxes.

[Reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/raiseevent-statement) for this topic at MS

Class `cTextboxes`

```
   Option Explicit

    Private mcolTextboxes As Collection

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set mcolTextboxes = New Collection
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(ByRef nTextbox As MSForms.Textbox, index As Long)
        Dim mTextbox As cTextbox
        Set mTextbox = New cTextbox
        mTextbox.index = index
        Set mTextbox.Parent = Me
        Set mTextbox.Textbox = nTextbox
        mcolTextboxes.Add mTextbox
    End Sub

    Public Function InitBoxes()
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To mcolTextboxes.Count
            mcolTextboxes.Item(i).Enabled = False
            mcolTextboxes.Item(i).Backcolor = &H80000016
        Next i
    End Function
Public Function enableBox(index As Long)
    If index <= mcolTextboxes.Count Then
        mcolTextboxes.Item(index).Enabled = True
        mcolTextboxes.Item(index).Backcolor = &H80000005
    End If
End Function
Public Function disableBox(index As Long)
    If index <= mcolTextboxes.Count Then
        mcolTextboxes.Item(index).Enabled = False
        mcolTextboxes.Item(index).Backcolor = &H80000016
    End If
End Function
```

Class `cTextbox`

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mTextbox As MSForms.Textbox
Private WithEvents mTextChange As cTextboxChange


Dim mParent As Object
Dim mIndex As Long

Public Property Set Textbox(tb As MSForms.Textbox)
    Set mTextbox = tb
    Set mTextChange = New cTextboxChange
End Property
Property Let index(nIndex As Long)
    mIndex = nIndex
End Property
Property Get index() As Long
    index = mIndex
End Property
Public Property Set Parent(nParent As Object)
    Set mParent = nParent
End Property
Public Property Get Parent()
    Set Parent = mParent
End Property
Property Let Enabled(nEnabled As Boolean)
    mTextbox.Enabled = nEnabled
End Property
Property Let Backcolor(color As Long)
    mTextbox.Backcolor = color
End Property

Private Sub mTextBox_Change()
    mTextChange.ChangeIt
End Sub

Private Sub mTextChange_EnableBox()

    If mTextbox.TextLength > 0 Then
        mParent.enableBox index + 1
    Else
        mParent.disableBox index + 1
    End If

End Sub
```

Class `cTextboxChange`

```
Option Explicit

Public Event enableBox()

Public Sub ChangeIt()
    RaiseEvent enableBox
End Sub
```

The userform itself contains as an example four textboxes and contains the following code

```
Option Explicit

Dim colTextboxes As cTextboxes

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Set colTextboxes = New cTextboxes

    colTextboxes.Add Me.TextBox1, 1
    colTextboxes.Add Me.TextBox2, 2
    colTextboxes.Add Me.TextBox3, 3
    colTextboxes.Add Me.TextBox4, 4
    colTextboxes.InitBoxes

End Sub
```